# Is this a stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

IS this bit of code in PHP/mysql considered a stored procedure?

```
$sql = 'SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = ? AND passwordHash = ?';
$result = $db->query($sql, array($_POST['username'], $passwordHash));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It's just a query. The fact that is hard-coded in something else (in this case, PHP) does not make it a stored procedure.

A stored procedure is stored *inside* the database. See also [the manual on stored routines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html)

Answer (score 4):

A stored procedure is a piece of SQL that is stored on the SQL server.

Like [wikipedia describes it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) :

> A stored procedure is a subroutine
>   available to applications accessing a
>   relational database system.
>
> Stored procedures (sometimes called a
>   proc, sproc, StoPro, or SP) are
>   actually stored in the database data
>   dictionary.

If you are working with a MySQL database, you might want to take a look at this section of the manual : [Chapter 19. Stored Programs and Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-views.html)

Here, your SQL code is not stored on the SQL server : it is written directly in your PHP script.

So, no, this is not a stored procedure -- it's a simple SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

No. It's just a simple execution of SQL on a database. No stored procedure or method call.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I can see.

This is simply a SQL Select statement with parameters.

MySQL reference on stored routines

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html

Answer (score 2):

It's not. Stored procedures looks like this:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
 BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
 END
```

(from mysql documentation)